# for loop, $i equals two different values in the same loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small form that is generated from a `mysqli->query` and I've set each inputs name to be an array, such as `name="Shift_ID[]"`. Then I have a `for loop` that is meant to `UPDATE` the records one at a time as it loops through. The problem I have is that the `$i` variable is a different value within the same loop and I don't understand why. This is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['update_submit']))
{
    $id = $_POST['Shift_ID'];
    $name = $_POST['Shift_Name'];
    $short_name = $_POST['Shift_Short_Name'];
    $color  = $_POST['Shift_Color'];
    $shift_total_records = "5";

    for($i = 0; $i <= $shift_total_records; $i++) 
    {
        $sql = ("UPDATE shift SET Shift_ID = '$id[$i]', Shift_Name = '$name[$i]', Shift_Short_Name = '$short_name[$i]', Shift_Color = '$color[$i]' WHERE Shift_ID = '$i'");

        echo "SQL: " . $sql . "<br>";

        if(!$result_shift_update = $mysqli->query($sql))
        {
            die ('There was an error updating the shift table [' . $mysqli->error . ']');
        }
    }
}
```

The `echo` returns this:

```
SQL: UPDATE shift SET Shift_ID = '1', Shift_Name = 'Morning', Shift_Short_Name = 'AM', Shift_Color = '#FF0000' WHERE Shift_ID = '0'
```

I was expecting `Shift_ID = '1'` and `WHERE Shift_ID = '1'`. Can someone explain why this is happening? Also, before someone says it, I do know this is open to injection attacks and I need to use prepared statements.

**EDIT: ** The reason I had it `Shift_ID = '$id[$i]'` and `WHERE Shift_ID = '$i'` was because I wanted to user to be able to change the `Shift_ID` field if they wanted to. The point would be to have the option to rearrange the order. The `Shift_ID` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, so they would get an error if they tried to use the same number twice, but is there a way to make this do what I want?

Comment: that is a ridiculous assumption..

Comment: In the beginning 1 is values of $id[0] and in the end it is 0 only.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath are you referring to the assumption that someone is going to make a comment about injection attacks? :)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath wouldn't it be more "constructive" to explain what it is you're talking about then? Neither one of your comments make sense. Please tell me what was "a ridiculous assumption" so that I can improve my question.

Comment: the assumption that $i changes when you don't modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used a different variable in each location. Do you mean this:

```
$sql = ("UPDATE shift SET Shift_ID = '$id[$i]', Shift_Name = '$name[$i]', Shift_Short_Name = '$short_name[$i]', Shift_Color = '$color[$i]' WHERE Shift_ID = '$id[$i]'");
```

Comment: I'm sorry, to me that looks the same as what I have.

Comment: Oops! You are right, I didn't see that. Actually it is suppose to be that way `Shift_ID = '$id[$i]'` because I want to update that field as well.

Comment: This wasn't quite what I had in mind. I was hoping to make it so if the user wanted to change the `Shift_ID` number, they could. However, I didn't make that point clear in my question and so that is on me. I've updated my question. Do you know if that's possible and if so, how would I do it?

Comment: I didn't write `WHERE Shift_ID='$id[$i]`, you did. I had `WHERE Shift_ID='$i` thinking that it would use the `$i` variable in two ways. Obviously I was wrong.

Comment: I've just read through your edit. Allowing a user to change the UID of a table record is a big no. Create a new column and use that to *order* shifts

Comment: Cool, that makes sense. I've marked your answer as accepted as that is ultimately what I'm going to use. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The first '1' is `$id[$i]` not `$i` - there is no problem evident here.

Answer (score 2):

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $shift_total_records; $i++)
```

sets $i to 0, when you echo $id[$i] you will get the content in $id[0], the first id, but when you only echo $i you print 0 because you made $id = 0.

Comment: I tried this as well, but that's not what happens. I get the same scenario no matter what I set $i to. If I set it `$i=1` then the first result is 1 and the second is 2

Answer (score 1):

The first time you use $i you use it as follows `$id[$i]` the second time you just use `$i`....

Comment: That was on purpose, although I understand why you noticed that. I've updated my question. Thanks!